# Question about converting a polar equation to a rectangular equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\sec\theta =2$$

So I went through all the steps and got:

$$\cos\theta =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } $$

$$\sin\theta =\pm \sqrt { 1-\frac { 1 }{ 4 }  } $$

$$\sin\theta =\pm \frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 } $$

$$y=\pm {\sqrt { 3 }  }$$

Now why is it that the correct answer has an $x$ in it and why can't I give the answer $x^2+y^2=4$?

Comment: Your last line implies that $y = 2\sin \theta$, which is not true

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's clearly not true because $y = r\sin \theta$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \sec \theta = 2 $$
$$ 1 = 2 \cos \theta $$
$$ r = 2 r\cos \theta $$
$$ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 2x $$
$$ x^2 + y^2 = 4x^2 $$
$$ 3x^2 = y^2 $$
$$ y = \pm \sqrt{3} \,x$$

Another method: 
$$ \cos \theta = \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \tan \theta = \pm \sqrt{3} = \frac{y}{x} \Rightarrow y = \pm \sqrt{3} \,x $$

Comment: ok, this one I believe. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From $\sec\theta=2$, draw a triangle in either the first or fourth quadrant with angle $\theta$, adjacent side $1$, opposite side $\sqrt 3$, hypotenuse $2$. Then
\begin{align}
\sec\theta=2\implies \tan\theta&=\pm\sqrt{3}\\
{r\sin\theta\over r\cos\theta}&=\pm \sqrt{3}\\
{y\over x}&=\pm \sqrt{3}\\
y&=\pm \sqrt{3}\,x.
\end{align}

Comment: $\tan \theta$ = opposite/adjacent = $\sqrt{3}$